# Maintain scroll position in listboxes in updatepanels, NOT the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have a listbox inside an update panel.  When I scroll down and select an item, it scrolls back to the top of the listbox.  I heard that the dom does not keep track of the scroll position on a postback.  Does anyone have a solution/example on how to solve this?

Thanks,
XaiSoft

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're running into this problem because the `UpdatePanel` completely replaces your scrolled `<select>` element with a new one when the asynchronous request comes back.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Use JavaScript to store the `scrollTop` property of the `<select>` element in a hidden form element before the `UpdatePanel` is submitted (by calling the `ClientScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement` method) and then setting it on the new `<select>` when the AJAX call comes back. This will be tedious, error-prone, and probably not very compatible (see [here](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2007/06/setting-vertical-scroll-property-in.html)).
2. Use JavaScript to store the `<select>`'s `selectedIndex` property and re-select that item when the AJAX call comes back. Obviously this won't work if the user hasn't selected anything yet.
3. **[Don't use `UpdatePanel`s](http://encosia.com/2007/07/11/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/)**. Try [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) + [ASP.NET page methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) instead.

Comment: I found this solution and it actually worked.

http://basgun.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/maintain-scroll-position-updatepanel-postback/

Comment: Good. It sounds like there's a problem with selectTop on IE6. The first comment on this page explains how you can get around it: http://geekswithblogs.net/lorint/archive/2005/12/16/63289.aspx

Answer (score 4):

```
    var xPos, yPos;
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        if (($get('Panel1')) != null) {
            xPos = $get('Panel1').scrollLeft;
            yPos = $get('Panel1').scrollTop;
        }
    }

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        if (($get('Panel1')) != null) {
            $get('Panel1').scrollLeft = xPos;
            $get('Panel1').scrollTop = yPos;
        }
    }
    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    //Note: "Panel1" Panel or div u want to maintain scroll position
    //Note: This Java Script should be added after Scriptmanager*****
```

//Maintain Scroll Position for Panel/Div with out Update panel

```
    window.onload = function() {
        var strCook = document.cookie;
        if (strCook.indexOf("!~") != 0) {
            var intS = strCook.indexOf("!~");
            var intE = strCook.indexOf("~!");
            var strPos = strCook.substring(intS + 2, intE);
            document.getElementById('Panel1').scrollTop = strPos;
        }
    }
    function SetDivPosition() {
        var intY = document.getElementById('Panel1').scrollTop;
        document.title = intY;
        document.cookie = "yPos=!~" + intY + "~!";
    }


   //Note: "Panel1" Panel id or div id for which u want to maintain scroll position
```

Comment: I had to make a slight modification and use the following to make it work: `yPos = $('#<%=MyListBox.ClientID %>').scrollTop();` to extract the data in `beginRequestHandler`, and `$('#<%=MyListBox.ClientID %>').scrollTop(yPos);` to put it back in `endRequestHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the following code example scrolls in the following way:

- Internet Explorer 8: After postback the selected item is the first visible item.
- Firefox: After postback the selected item is always visible (but might be the last visible item).
- Chrome: After postback, the selected item might be hidden since the listbox scrolls to the top, as you say.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListBox ID="lb1" runat="server" Height="100px" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem>A</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>B</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>C</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>D</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>E</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>F</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>G</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>H</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Firefox scrolls to the top unpredictably for selected items.  At first, I thought it might be because of the number of items in the listbox, but when select a particular item... sometimes it stays visible after a postback, and sometimes firefox scrolls to the top instead.  The list isn't being rebuilt and the same thing happened when any item is clicked, so it's clearly a firefox bug, and it's still present as of version 3.0.13.

Answer (score 0):

You can still achieve the partial postback using the `UpdatePanel` containing a `ListBox`, but prevent it from being overwritten by a new instance by setting the following on the `UpdatePanel`:

```
ChildrenAsTriggers="False"
```

This as stated in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.childrenastriggers.aspx):

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether postbacks from immediate
>   child controls of an UpdatePanel control update the panel's content.
>   Set the ChildrenAsTriggers property to false if do NOT you want
>   postbacks from immediate child controls of the UpdatePanel control to
>   cause an update of the panel's content.

The one caveat to this is if you are trying to do any other visual manipulation to the ListBox from the server-side (i.e. adding `CSS` attributes to the items on postbacks), then you will not see them render until another unrelated postback occurs. If all you are doing is making selections than setting `ChildrenAsTriggers="False"` will work.

Answer (score 0):

For the enterprise application I was working on, it turned out that the MasterPage.Master page was handling the Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest event and setting window.scroll(0,0) within it. The content pages were obviously executing the window.scroll(0,0) on each trigger of the contentpage's UpdatePanel. I tried overriding the add_endRequest functionality in the content page but could not get that to work. Eventually I just modified the Master.Master to not do window.scroll(0,0).