# focus and set focus and yet i need to scroll down

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have some problem with my website :
I have an ajax updatepanel that sends to the server some text from a textbox as the user click a button.

I set a **focus method** in the **page load** + **focus method** click event to the **textbox** + on the **aspx code**, I set a **deafaultfocus**.

but I have a problem that although the focus is working, its scrolling it up a bit, to the begining of the page.  **while my intention is that it will stay without scrolling**.

how can I do that ?

Thanks!

Comment: have a look at this one for some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543131/maintain-scroll-position-in-listboxes-in-updatepanels-not-the-page

Comment: You can't avoid that. Focusing an element will also change the scrolling accordingly, it's browser behavior.