# how to make listbox scroll to the selected item in c# asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I'm trying to make listbox scroll to the selected item in the list.Can any one tell how to go about doing this in C# asp.net web application?

Comment: visit this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543131/maintain-scroll-position-in-listboxes-in-updatepanels-not-the-page

Comment: dere is a solution but its not working for my case

Comment: Here is a some problem as your problem you can check out 
[click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840034/how-to-scroll-selected-item-in-asp-listbox-in-multiple-mode

Answer (score -1):

Check [MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx) property. You can find it and set it at the Page directive.