# How to never refresh UpdatePanel on post back?

Tags: asp.net

I would like to embed a `ListBox` into an `UpdatePanel`. The `ListBox` needs to have multi select enabled, with a post back triggered on item selection. My problem is the scroll bar on postback. It gets back to the top everytime an item is clicked. I have tried different ways to back up the scroll position, there is just always something wrong with it (at least in IE8, the browser I have to focus on). Either I get a flicker, or as soon as the user uses his mouse wheel after post back, the scroll bar will then jump back to the top. This does not happen in Chrome and Mozilla.

I was thinking, maybe there is something that should work - posting back without ever redrawing my `ListBox` / udpating the containing UpdatePanel ? Is this possible ?

Comment: Can you add further comments about 'scroll bar that does not behave nicely'. Thanks

Comment: Have edited, even though my interest has more to do with the UpdatePanel refresh features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any full postback will necessarily repaint a list view so maintaining the scroll position of the listview is going to be problematic

**Smart Nav**

If it is the position of the page scroll position you are struggling with then you could try smart navigation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx

I don't think browser coverage is going to be hugely reliable for this (for example see http://forums.asp.net/p/1094179/1651390.aspx)

**Update Panels and postback controls**

If you are just updating the content in the update panel then it shouldn't lose it's page position. Make sure you are doing the partial post back and not the full. The listbox and the control triggering the postback should both be within the update panel.

There are caveats to this though - if you have a button outside of the update panel it can trigger the partial postback if it is in the triggers collection of the panel (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.triggers.aspx)

**JQuery AJAX**

The nuclear option would be to use JQuery AJAX or similar e.g. proper AJAX not the strange fake halfway house stuff that the update panels use (not to say that they aren't very useful - just need to be used judiciously). JQuery AJAX is a swine to get working within the postback architecture so I wouldn't necessarily recommend.

**Maintaining the ListBox scroll position**

Note - if it is the listbox scroll position that you are concerned about them this question

[Maintain scroll position in listboxes in updatepanels, NOT the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543131/maintain-scroll-position-in-listboxes-in-updatepanels-not-the-page?rq=1)

gives some good advice
Hope that helps some

Comment: The scroll position that is of interest is the <select>'s, the page's scroll position does not matter

Answer (score 0):

I think flickers could always happen whatever you do (flickering is actually the browser that renders contents in several phases).

You should start by trying the MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack page's property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx

Comment: thanks, I've tried the MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack but that would only work for the page. Also, it is known to not work with master pages (I have one)

Comment: The flicker is not so much a problem, the scroll bar going back to the top when the user mouse-scrolls is.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to postback on every item selection ? Don't you mean an async postback ?
I had a similar issue with a ListBox inside a user control, and who in turn was in an UpdatePanel.  I used jQuery to deal with click events on two buttons that were selecting and unselecting all items in the listbox.

Try this:

Create a .js file (e.g. select.js) and insert your jQuery code in there. Something like:

```
function pageLoad() {

    //insert code here
}
```

Important to use pageLoad() instead of (document).ready.

Then, insert the script reference in your ScriptManager:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="True">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Select.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```